# How to combine data in msgpack format?

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, msgpack

There is a struct name `Model` defined as follows:

```
struct Model {
  1: string a,
  2: string b,
  3: long c
}
```

And I have only `string` serialized from `Model` at remote computer as follows, when I can't see definition above.

```
  Model m1;
  m1.set_a("a");
  m1.set_b("b");
  Model m2;
  m2.set_c(1);

  std::string data1;
  std::string data2;
  // use msgpack
  Pack(m1, &data1);
  Pack(m2, &data2);
```

How can I combine these two strings into one which can be deserialized to an object of `Model`?
In a word, I need a `function` like this: `bool CombineMsgpack(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2, std::string *out);`

Comment: If you can tell me the rules for combining messages then I can write you the function.  What are the rules for combining messages ?  eg what happens if the same fields exist in both messages; what about missing fields etc ?

Comment: I want to take out all the set fields of the second one and set them to the first, and replace the field of the first if the same fields exist. How can I do? Thank you very much.

Comment: m1 is packed as an array of string, string, int. The last int is uninitialized value (any value). m2 is packed as an array of empty-string, empty-string, 1.Both m1 an m2 fully set values. So you need to define overwriting rule. In addition, you can't overwrite them on serialized images. You need to unpack them and do the overwrite process and then, pack overwritten Model.